# Cartesian Product Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class CartesianProduct
include Enumerable
# your code here
end
#Examples of use
c = CartesianProduct.new([:a,:b], [4,5])
c.each { |elt| puts elt.inspect }
# [:a, 4]
# [:a, 5]
# [:b, 4]
# [:b, 5]
c = CartesianProduct.new([:a,:b], [])
c.each { |elt| puts elt.inspect }
# (nothing printed since Cartesian product
# of anything with an empty collection is empty)
```

I am new to ruby. And I understand how to define a instance method of Cartesian Product, but I have no clue to this. How should I construct the class object to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking for? How should you construct what? Are you trying to create a class called 'CartesianProduct' that would do what is shown?

Comment: Yes, it requires a class method. I know how to construct a instance method to return a value, but I don't know how to construct class method to modify the value of a class object.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, that's OK, people will try to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: length of the product is fixed to 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use a class for that, but keeping the structure of the question, I'd write:

```
class CartesianProduct
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(xs, ys)
    @xs = xs
    @ys = ys
  end

  def each
    return to_enum unless block_given?
    @xs.each do |x| 
      @ys.each { |y| yield [x, y] }
    end
  end
end
```

Instead, I'd simply write `xs.product(ys)` or build my own `Array#lazy_product` if laziness were important (see this [ticket](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6499)).

Comment: There is no need to use lazy, though, is there? Straight out `each` and a `yield` will be simpler and faster

Comment: ok, you were right, though to be honest I prefered the lazy version, it's a more functional approach (and returned an enumerator if used without block, like a standard `each`).

Comment: Indeed, you should probably start with the typical `return to_enum unless block_given?`

Answer (score 30):

I suggest using [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product).

```
[:a, :b].product [4,5]
```

Which will yield the output you want.

```
irb(main):001:0> [:a, :b].product [4,5]
=> [[:a, 4], [:a, 5], [:b, 4], [:b, 5]]
irb(main):002:0>
```

If you want a lazy generator of permutations, I have written something like this before. But I warn you, if you have a large number of permutations to compute it might take a while. You should be able to take what you need from the first 40 - 45 lines of [this file](https://github.com/rk/werd/blob/master/grammartest.rb) (this file was an experiment anyway).

The trick is to build enumerators using Ruby 1.9.2 to work your way through an array of arrays. So you first build an enumerator that will endlessly cycle through an array, and in your array-of-array enumerator you track the first output set and end the loop when that is hit a second time. This was the only way I could figure out how to terminate such a loop.

```
def infinite_iterator(array)
  Enumerator.new do |result|
    loop do
      array.cycle { |item| result << item }
    end
  end
end

def cartesian_iterator(data)
  Enumerator.new do |result|
    first = data.map { |p| p.next }
    result << first

    i = 1
    parts = first.dup
    loop do
      parts[2-i] = data[2-i].next
      break if parts == first

      result << parts.join
      i = ((i + 1) % parts.size)
    end
  end
end

array = [ infinite_iterator([:a,:b]), infinite_iterator([4,5]) ]
generator = cartesian_iterator(array)

generator.each { |a| p a }
```

Comment: what about two empty array? What will be the  result?

Comment: A much better way: use `enum_for`/`to_enum`, e.g. `generator = (0..99999).to_a.to_enum(:product, (0..99999).to_a)`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to define an `each` method in your class that calls `yield` for every combination of the product.

You could use `Array#product`, but it returns an array, so it is not lazy.

There is a [proposal for `Array.product`](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6499) in Ruby 2.0 that would do just that.