# Iterate through multiple arrays, in a different way

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Although I'm trying to solve this problem in Ruby, I'm welcome to suggestions in other languages that I can take back to Ruby.

I have any array:

```
color = ["red", "green", "blue"]
size = ["small", "medium", "large"]
style = ["loose", "tight"]
```

I need to create strings for **every** possible combination. For example:

```
"red small loose", "red small tight", "red medium loose", "red medium tight", "red large loose", "red large tight", "green small loose", etc...
```

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: What you're doing is called a _Cartesian product_. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352061/cartesian-product-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>> color.product(size, style).map { |strings| strings.join(" ") }
#=> ["red small loose", "red small tight", ..., "blue large tight"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of arrays is not too high (lower than 5) you could write nested loops. Semicode:

```
for x = 0; x < color.size; x ++
    for y = 0; y < color.size; y ++
        for z = 0; z < color.size; z ++
            return color[x] + size[y] + style[z]
            z = z+1
        y = y+1
    x = x+1
```

Though I have zero knowledge of Ruby, this would basically work.

Comment: Except in Ruby we really eschew using `for` loops, and `++` isn't an operator.

Comment: That's why I posted it as semi-code. I assume a developer in any language can translate this to his specific needs. My answer is basically what xdazz posted.

Comment: Well, it seems like a safe assumption that it would "basically work", until you read all the questions on SO about "Why doesn't `++` work with Ruby?".

Answer (score 0):

Ruby provides `product` method for array, or you could just use loops.

```
color.each do |color|
  size.each do |size|
    style.each do |style|
      puts "#{color} #{size} #{style} "
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: idiomatically iterators :)

Answer (score 0):

`color.product(size, style)` will do the work